# Redirection from https to http not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've tried with multiple conditions to redirect all my `https` pages to `http` as my SSL certificate has expired. As it is taking time to reflect the changes, I want to redirect all those requests made by https to be called over http.

Tried with these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my_site.com/$1 [NC,L,R]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Nothing seems to be working. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: What actually happens - literally nothing? Or an error? Does your site work if you type the HTTP URL directly? Have you cleared your browser cache? (You presumably had a HTTP to HTTPS 301 implemented previously - this will have been cached hard by the browser.) Have you implemented HSTS? Are you using a CDN? Do you have other directives? Other `.htaccess` files? mod_rewrite enabled? `.htaccess` enabled?

Comment: @w3dk Everything is working, Thanks! It was happening because the rules were applied at the starting of the file. I tried placing them at the end of the file and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved by placing the rules at the end of the file instead of placing them at the starting of the file

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. However, placing these directives at the end of the file doesn't really make sense - these directives should (in fact, I would say "must") go at the start of the file. If the same directive is working, having moved it to the end of the file, then I would assume that the problem was "something else" (eg. cache or something)? If you keep the directive at the end of the file then it is highly likely that any additional directives that you later add will prevent this redirect from happening.

Comment: @w3dk Yeah, some rule after the redirection rules must have over written this rule and redirected the URL to https again. However, it worked and helped me at the last moment. Now, the SSL certificate is registered and updated. I am now running the site over https again :)